# How to automatically use SIP/VOIP for international calls?

Tags: nexus-5, phone-app, voip

I have a cell phone plan that includes 9 hours of national calls, however, international calls are billed at extreme minute-rates. For this reason I use VOIP/SIP for international calls thorugh the built-in SIP option (dialer > menu > settings > call settings > accounts).

The built-in dialer have 3 options to choose betweeen, and none of them are what I am looking for - Use Internet calling:
1) for all calls when data network is available
2) only for internet calls
3) ask for each call

It would be so simple to have the dialer check the number called, and if it's an international number (i.e. it starts by +) then use VOIP, otherwise use standard cell calls.

Unless I am blind I don't suppose there are any way of doing this with the built-in dialer. I frankly don't understand why not, I would have thought this is a fairly common situation in this day and age.

Is there a way that could solve the problem?

I know I could have two dialers, but it annoys me that something as simple and obvious can't be done automatically.